# Having properties that return copies of objects in the getter, and retain objects in the setter

Tags: objective-c, properties, copy, retain

I have a problem understanding properties.
What kind of property should I write if I want an attribute not be modified by its accessors (return by copy) and be set by reference (retain).

Example :

```
MyType* theAttribute = MyObject.attribute;
[theAttribute changeSomething]; // Does not have to change the MyObject attribute, working with a copy return

MyType tmpObject = [[MyType alloc] init];
MyObject.attribute = tmpObject; // Want a retain here
[tmpObject release];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare the property as retain in the header:

```
@property (nonatomic. retain) MyType *attribute;
```

In the implementation file synthesize the iVar:

```
@synthesize attribute;
```

But provide your own getter which will override the synthesized one:

```
- (MyType)attribute {
    return [attribute copy];
}
```

I know I'm not autoreleasing the returned object, but since the question doesn't specify iOS, I'm writing this from the perspective of a garbage collected environment.

Comment: As `atomic` is the default, you need to also write the `setter`.  You can't mix synthesized getters with manually written setters or vice-versa.   (GCC may let this pass, but it is wrong.  LLVM 2.0 correctly warns/errors on such shenanigans.)

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I've amended my answer

Answer (score 2):

In such case you should write getter and setter by yourself.

Comment: You don't need to write the setter by yourself, just the getter.

Comment: Yeah, really, I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to write the setter yourself if you want to use `atomic`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably write your own accessor(s), but exactly how depends on whether you want the copied "get" return to be autoreleased or not:

1. The idiomatic way of accomplishing "copy" this is to have a normal "retain" property for accessors, and support the `-copy` or `-mutableCopy` method also. The latter two are the standard for semantically copying an object, and the returned object should have a retain ownership.
2. If you want to have the accessor `-foo` return a copy of "foo" so that the caller can't manipulate the internal version, that's OK, but then you'd write it yourself to look like this:

-

```
- (Foo *)foo
{
    return [[foo copy] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Uhhh... Does not [foo copy] returns a retained object ? Autoreleasing a retained object ?

Comment: @Oliver: Yes, `[foo copy]` returns a retained object, but by convention, the getter `-foo` should not, hence the autorelease. The resulting effect is both what the callee wants (a copy of the original data to be returned) and what the caller expects (an object that can be dropped without an explicit release call).

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest not returning by copy.  This will snag you up in memory management.  Is it auto-released?  Not retain'd?  Too many questions.

Instead, I recommend this:

```
MyType* attr = [MyType typeWithMyType:MyObject.attribute];
```

or something.

Comment: There aren't any questions if you follow the easy memory management rules; Methods return autoreleased objects, and you only release what you alloc, retain, copy, or mutable copy. Also, this way requires the consumer of the class to use a copy and not change the object, while passing a copy enforces this by design which frees up worrying about whether to copy values returned by getters or not.

Comment: But that's the point.  A retain'd property that returns an autoreleased copy violates all of those rules and naming conventions.

Comment: Why? The getter doesn't affect the object stored as a property and just returns a copy. How does the memory management of a _copy_ affect the memory management of the _original_?

Comment: because... `[MyObject.myProp setVar:myVar]` doesn't modify the var of MyObject's Property.  It modifies the copy, where MyObject.myProp doesn't specify that it returns a copy.  `[MyString stringWithString:]` you know returns an `autorelease`'d object.  What happens if you subsequently want to link that property to a value in an editable table or the like?  It'll only effect the copy.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but knowing which object you're pointing to is part of memory management.

Comment: The OP specifically wanted to return a copy to prevent the changes happening to the iVar outside of the objects control. And the point of memory management is that you don't need to know what object you are pointing to, just whether you are responsible for releasing it when you are done with it.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani : that's the point. If you write [MyObject.myProp setVar:myVar], it changes the copy and this is what I want. Writing [self.myProp setVar:myVar] also does that. If I want to change the original value, I want to force [__myProp setVar:myVar] from inside the class. If you call MyObject/self.myProp.var = something from inside or outside, it changes the copy. And you won't be able to call MyObject.__myProp, so doing this I have a private member that cannot be modified from outside the class, with a forced setter.

Comment: @Oliver, I still think it's bad form - but it's your future headache and not mine.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani : That's sure, that's not very conventional, but I want to test the beast to tame it :-) Then I'll return to conventional things  :-)